# Loading same view on different visual states causes conflict

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm using Visual States to show / hide some of my views.

On 2 of those views, I load a sub-view that the 2 views use using ViewModels. Something like this:

```
<local:SharedSubView DataContext="{Binding Path=SharedSubViewVM}" />
```

Problem is, I think it causes conflict because when I try to load the 2 views, it just hangs.

Is there another way to do this? Or should I just create another duplicate file for the view?

Thank you

Comment: This looks totally valid... we need a more complete example ... define "hangs up" for starters... does it throw an exception?

Comment: The SharedSubView is actually a textbox that allows users to 'search' for things. When the textbox is changed, SharedSubView loads a ListView of all matching items.

What happens is, when I try to search, I only am able to get in 1 character before the app hangs. The items load, but I can't click anything anymore and the mouse pointer remains as a 'I' selector (the one for text boxes.

Comment: Just add the relevant code to the question

Comment: I think I got it. I was using a static Instance that the 2 was referencing. I just created separate instances for the 2 views and it worked nicely. Thanks for the help.